# Angular app deployed with bicep keeps getting 403?

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-bicep

I recently started to convert the company i'm working in to IaC with bicep. In the process i'm also learning bicep. I deployed our api app without a problem but the angular application keeps getting 403 forbidden error.

FYI, it was not displaying anything and getting 502 timeout eventually until I fixed the runtime to node 18 lts.

here is my bicep module and my pipeline task. I couldn't find much on the internet, does anyone had the situation or know a solution?

main. Bicep

```
module webAppService 'modules/appService.bicep' = {
  name: webAppServiceName
  params: {
    location: defaultLocation
    uniqPrefix: webAppServiceName
    runtime: 'NODE:18LTS'
    isLinux: false
    isStandalone: false
    parentPlanId: apiAppService.outputs.appServicePlanId
  }
}
```

appService.bicep

```
param location string = 'West Europe'
param uniqPrefix string
param runtime string
param isLinux bool = true
param isStandalone bool = true
param parentPlanId string = ''

var appServiceAppName = '${uniqPrefix}-app'
var appServicePlanName = '${uniqPrefix}-plan'

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = if(isStandalone) {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  kind: isLinux ? 'linux' : 'windows'
  sku: {
    name: 'F1'
    tier: 'Free'
    size: 'F1'
    family: 'F'
    capacity: 1
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: isLinux
  }
}

var siteConfig = isLinux ? {
  linuxFxVersion: runtime
} : {
  windowsFxVersion: runtime
  netFrameworkVersion: 'v6.0'
}

resource appServiceApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: appServiceAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    serverFarmId: isStandalone ? appServicePlan.id : parentPlanId
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: siteConfig
  }
}

output appServicePrincipal string = appServiceApp.identity.principalId
output webAppName string = appServiceAppName
output url string = appServiceApp.properties.defaultHostName
output appServicePlanId string = appServicePlan.id
```

task.yaml

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(serviceConnectionName)
    ResourceGroupName: $(tenant)
    appType: 'Web App On Linux'
    WebAppName: $(webAppName)
    packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/web-ci/drop/publish/publish.zip'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag: false
    startUpCommand: 'npm start'
```